# Moving on to next route if some url cannot be found

Tags: laravel-5

I am working on an application using Laravel 5.4, VueJS, AXIOS, VueRouter. VueRouter is responsible for all of the navigation in the application, save for the route config below:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Auth::routes();


Route::get('/{catchall?}', ['as' => 'start', 'middleware' => 'auth', function() {
    return view('home')->with([...]);
}])->where('catchall', '.*');
```

This essentially redirects the user to the 'base' blade file, which contains the `<router-link></routerlink>`.

However, I am now implementing a page in my application that anyone can access (not requiring the auth middleware), and utilizes a different layout entirely (so needs a new blade file).

Preferably, it would be accessed like this:

`app.sample.com/{some-string}`

Rather than something else like this:

`app.sample.com/survey/{some-string}`

`{some-string}` is a randomly generated string that is then thrown into the DB. accessible by one of my models. As I understand it, I could do something like this:

`Route::get('/{some-string}', 'SomeController@somemethod')`

Placing this above the catchall should work. However, in the case that `/{some-string}` does not match anything in the DB, I would prefer that it gets handled by the catchall, which will serve the `home.blade.php`

Is there any clean way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're essentially describing the RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware, at least thats how I would approach this. Utilize middleware to check a user's authentication level and do any route matching before serving them through to the application.

Comment: That's a great point -- didn't even think to approach the problem in that way. Makes sense to me!